# Foreign character keyboard input in C# XNA

Tags: c#, winforms, xna-4.0, keyboard-input

XNA supports only English keyboards, so I want to use System.Windows.Forms's KeyPress event. But I can't. Why?

I tried my own codes:

```
// 1st
FromHandle(Window.Handle).FindForm().KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(KeyPressEvent);
// 2nd
FromHandle(Window.Handle).FindForm().KeyPress += KeyPressEvent;
```

After I found and tried a solution from stackoverflow:

> ```
> using System.Windows.Forms;
>
> ...
>
> var form = (Form)Form.FromHandle(window.Handle);
> form.KeyPress += form_KeyPress;
>
> ...
>
> private void form_KeyPress(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
> {  
>     Console.WriteLine(e.KeyChar);
>     e.Handled = true;
> }
> ```

I tried these solutions in a new, empty C# XNA project, too, but none of them worked. What have I done wrong?